# Hibernate and cyrillic

Tags: java, hibernate, utf-8, cyrillic

I want to add some russian text into table. It works fine if I will do using MySQL, but not Hibernate.
This makes my text look `????`:

```
public void addHeadHunter(String city, Integer salary) {

        Session session = null;

        session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session
                .createSQLQuery(
                        "INSERT INTO headhunter VALUES(NULL,:city,:salary,NULL)")
                .setString("city", city).setInteger("salary", salary);
        int updated = query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

What's wrong, comrades?

Comment: mostly it should be issue with your character encoding. Since you test you try to insert is not given. there is not other guess.

Answer (score 3):

In your Hibernate config file you'll need to add these properties:

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</prop>
```

This should allow the use of UTF-8 and support for cyrillic text.

Comment: Hmm, try modifying your connection URL property to include the characterEncoding option:  `<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/DB_NAME_HERE?characterEncoding=UTF-8</property>`